# Writing test cases for MOSS 2007 WCM

Tags: testing, 2007

Does somebody have a test case template for WCM solutions?

How should the test case be categorised? Is it based on page layouts?

Answer (score 1):

All testign depends on specifications, ofcourse. 
Generally WCM solution come with predefined navigational structure, site definitions, page layouts, with freedom of editor to create new sites, pages and normal list/ document content. 
Most important in my experience is to give structure to your test (it is all to easy to forget parts) and drill down from basic to more advanced. 
These steps I always execute:

1) Check navigational/site structure, site definitions and page layouts.

2) Check basic content editing and webparts (e.g. create new sites, pages, and other content)

3) Check custom features/ jobs, etc. specific implemented for this client

4) Design check (cross browser) : especially here it is key to have reliable test content supplied by end user

5) Authorisation.

6) performance (note: watch out for functional issues because of cached content)

For simple sites you might just want to rpitn out specs and keep track of test on hardcopy.
For more complex site, you might put all items to check (navigational structure, site defintions, webparts,. etc) in excel to keep track of what has been tested.